# Infection Throws Exeption, but why, and how to handle it?

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony4, mutation-testing, infection

The Task is that the error does bot explain that problem right.

The Error:

> Project tests must be in a passing state before running Infection.
>     Infection runs the test suite in a RANDOM order. Make sure your tests do not have hidden dependencies.
>
> You can add these attributes to `phpunit.xml` to check it:
>
> If you don't want to let Infection run tests in a random order, set the `executionOrder` to some value, for example
>
> Check the executed command to identify the problem: '/usr/bin/php7.2' '-d' 'zend_extension=xdebug.so' '/mnt/e/dev/bin/phpunit' '--configuration' '/mnt/e/dev/var/infection/
>     infection/phpunitConfiguration.initial.infection.xml' '-vvv'
>     PHPUnit reported an exit code of 143.
>     Refer to the PHPUnit's output below:
>     STDERR:

Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded

What i try is simple to execute follow statement:

```
vendor/bin/infection --threads=10 --only-covered
```

But when I try that statement that explained in that error, the tests will run successfully, but that is only my unit tests without the mutation-testing.

Here is an abstract of phpunit tag in my phpunit.xml.dist

```
<phpunit .... backupGlobals="false" colors="false" bootstrap="/mnt/e/dev/RESTler/config/bootstrap.php" executionOrder="random" resolveDependencies="true" cacheResult="false" stopOnFailure="true" stderr="false" .../>
```

The Versions are:

- PHPUnit version: 7.5.15
- PHP 7.2.22-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
- Infection - PHP Mutation Testing Framework 0.14.2
- Symfony Framework 4.2

has anyone a hint of what I can try or where my error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my long Jurney i found something out.
But dont why it dosnt work with my configuration.

That was the right statement for me, after i remove the `xdebug.so` from my `php.ini`

```
infection --threads=10 --only-covered --initial-tests-php-options='-d zend_extension=xdebug.so'
```

I thought it would be enough but then came the memory_limit problem, that cam be fixed on the same way

```
infection --threads=10 --only-covered --initial-tests-php-options='-d zend_extension=xdebug.so -d memory_limit=-1'
```

Now it Runs and i have some todos :)

> .: killed, M: escaped, S: uncovered, E: fatal error, T: timed out
>
> .........M..MMMMMMM.M.M.MMM.MMMM.M.MMMMMMMM.MMMM.M   (50 / 89)
>   .....MM................MMMMMMM.MMMM....              (89 / 89)
>
> 89 mutations were generated:
>
> ```
>   45 mutants were killed
>
>    0 mutants were not covered by tests
>
>   44 covered mutants were not detected
>
>    0 errors were encountered
>
>    0 time outs were encountered
> ```
>
> Metrics:
>
> ```
>    Mutation Score Indicator (MSI): 50%
>    Mutation Code Coverage: 100%
>    Covered Code MSI: 50%
> ```

if somebody use `phpdbg` instead of `xdebug` and has that memory_limit issue, for me it has work if i had overwrite the new php.ini for phpdbg in my `/etc/php/7.3/phpdbg/php.ini`

*I hope this post here helps someone else once again. I do not delete it first. Maybe one day another mod.*